# Запятая перед "как"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Предложение такое: "Мне(,) как кинестетику(,) это очень важно". По идее, тут "как" в значении "в качестве", но просится запятая. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Виктор прав, оборот в данном случае имеет значение причины и обособляется, но я постараюсь дополнить и обобщить тему.

1. Среди оборотов с союзом КАК желательно различать обороты со значением сравнения и со значением тождества.
2. Оборот со значением тождества обособляется, если является приложением со значением причины  – аналогом придаточного предложения причины. Оборот может находиться в начале, в середине или в конце предложения.Как истинный художник, Пушкин видел поэтическое начало в самых простых вещах.Илюше иногда, как резвому мальчику, так и хочется всё переделать самому.Комендант посоветовал  мне оставить стихотворство, как дело службе противное.
3. Оборот со значением тождества не обособляется, если является обстоятельством в основном сообщении со значением «в качестве». Необособленный оборот обычно находится в конце (реже в начале) предложения и является, как правило, нераспространённым: Как художник  Лев Толстой гениален.  Лев Толстой гениален как художник.
4. Обороту "как кинестетик" можно придать значение "в качестве", например:  Как кинестетик он имеет определенные особенности поведения. Также в составе сказуемого: Он ведет себя как кинестетик.

Answer (score 2):

"Как" здесь, конечно, не "в качестве", а "потому что я кинестетик", поэтому запятые нужны